# App Store submit issue

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Since Xcode 6, i'm having problems submitting our app to the App Store.
I'm a member of a team and I have Admin permissions in our iTunes Connect account, until Xcode 6 I had no issues, and I was able to submit our apps to the App Store.
Now when I try I get a message that only the Agent can submit the app.

Is this something new? Is there a way for other members except the Agent to submit?

Comment: Try AppicationLoader under Xcode / Open Developer Tool. It seems to work better than Xcode sometimes, especially if you have multiple accounts.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store support, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)